# Carousel Indicators Beside It Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible in Bootstrap to have the carousel indicators beside the carousel?  I want some indicators on the right side to have font on them, so I know which slider I'm clicking on.

Picture to illustrate what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put the controls wherever you want, these are the tagas that make them work. `href="#myCarousel"` point to the carousel id and `data-slide="next"` sets the behavior:

```
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">next</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">prev</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNOOrQ

HTML

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Bootstrap carousel with number indicator</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Indicators --> 
      <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-numbers">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">Slide 1</li><br>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">Slide 2</li><br>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-indicators-numbers {
    li {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      left:140%;
      bottom: 150px;
      text-indent: 0;
      margin: 0 2px;
      width: 70px;
      height: 30px;
      border: none;
      line-height: 30px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #999;
      transition: all 0.25s ease;
      &.active, &:hover {
        margin: 0 2px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #337ab7;        
      }
    }
}
```